# Python invoking external application but not focussing

Tags: python, windows, flask, subprocess

I am using subprocess to run the external application from Python with following code, however the program is not focusing

```
subprocess.call([filename, param, param2])
```

I want the program should focus after open it (The new program should open as active window instead )

Comment: what does 'focus' mean in this context?

Comment: The new  program should open as active window instead